# Mysqli_real_escape_string preventing preg_split from working?

Tags: php, mysqli, preg-split

```
Example Text: This will be stored in the $_POST['x'] variable
This is sentence one.
This is sentence two.
This is sentence three.
```

If I run this code below It will return an array with only one element

```
$x= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['x']);
$y= preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", $x);
```

But if I run this code below it will split it correctly into all 3 elements.

```
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y= preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", $x);
```

Has anyone else experienced this phenomenon? Why does it happen?

Comment: why don't you output the before/after of $_POST['x'] and you'll probably see why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> http://php.net/mysqli-real-escape-string
>   Characters encoded are NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.

This means newlines become `\\n` (LF), `\\r` (CR) and `\\r\\n` (CRLF). Therefore they no longer match the regex.

In future, RTM ;)

Comment: Ahh, That makes perfect sense. Somehow I missed that

Comment: @Constarr generally escape string would be the last function you call before concatenating the value with a mysql query.

Comment: Yeah I see why. Knowing this will probably help me avoid mistakes many times down the road. I'm surprised I even figured out what was going on now. Thanks!